# convert base64 image to URL

Tags: node.js, base64

I am working with canvas creating images and saving them as base64 which when copied and pasted in browser shows the image fine. But I want to convert it to a link which can be clicked on to view the image. I am working with nodejs. Is there is a possible way to do it ?

Edit : I am working with a chatbot that makes a request to my API and excepts image link in the response

Comment: I think you mean to upload the image to your node.js and provide a public URL to download the image?

Comment: @EricWong no I don't want to upload it to the node.js server since all the data is already in the string I want this string to be in a link format which can be clicked on.

Comment: Well then just use data URL, like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgA....`, you can place this in a[href] and it will work